# Python: why should last class in MRO have zero parameter in its super's __init__ call or there would be runtime exception

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Suppose the class hierarchy is like below, and the parameters inside args are passed along the inheritance chain so that all classes get the parameter they need:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('A.__init__')
        self.a = args['a']
        super(A, self).__init__(**args)


class B (object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('B.__init__')
        self.b = args['b']
        # super(B, self).__init__(**args)

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('C.__init__')
        self.c = args['c']
        super(C, self).__init__(**args)


c = C(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(c.__dict__)
```

If class B calls super's __init__ with args, that is, uncomment this line

```
# super(B, self).__init__(**args)
```

, an exception is raised:

```
..., in __init__
    super(B, self).__init__(**args)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

It seems that the last class in the MRO couldn't call super's __init__, or could only call it with zero parameter. Would anyone explain why?

Suppose coder 0 writes class A and B, and then coder 1 writes class C to extend A & B. Since coder 0 doesn't know the actual MRO, how could he decide which class should call super's __init__ with args and which one shouldn't?

Or would anyone share the best practice of multiple inheritance together with parameter passing?

Comment: [This page](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) goes through some of the pitfalls of using `super()` and multiple inheritance, and some ways to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

The base class of `A` and `B` is `object`. `object` is a class that takes no parameters, because it doesn't do anything with them. (You can't write `object(1)`, can you?)

The best practice for solving this is to remove the consumed args before passing them along.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('A.__init__')
        self.a = args.pop("a")
        super(A, self).__init__(**args)


class B (object):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('B.__init__')
        self.b = args.pop("b")
        super(B, self).__init__(**args)

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        print('C.__init__')
        self.c = args.pop("c") # permanently removes 'c' from args
        super(C, self).__init__(**args)


c = C(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(c.__dict__)
```

Comment: Thank you Megalng, I see what's wrong with my code now. But consider this scenario: class A consumes parameters a & d, while class B consumes b & d. In this case, it's impossible to decide where to remove parameter d. My thought is that instead of letting class A & B extend class object directly, add a "Base" class which extends object and takes **args as the parameter of its \__init__, and let class A & B extend Base. Now all classes in the hierarchy take parameter **args.

Comment: @David Yes, If you have such a case, you have to do that. But often you then want a base class that consumes d for classes A & B